# Execute JavaScript function after all async postbacks

Tags: 2013, javascript

Just upgraded to SP2013. I have some JavaScript functions that need to be run after every (I'm assuming) async postback i.e. when a view is filtered or paged, so I can modify content in the view. Seems straight forward, but I can't get it working. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MyFunction);
```

I noticed the paging calls a "PageRefresh" function... is it possible to always run my code after that function is called? I'm running on very little sleep, I apologize if I am overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After careful dissecting, I realized the hash was being updated with every pagination and filter so I created a handler to execute my code.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
MyFunction(); 
});
```